# How to get the response to post string for eg in sign up i m facing error

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest

I m unable to signup the and i m no getting the response when i m trying to print it on on console so here is the code foe sign up form and i m unable to sign up now:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://fundedindia.org/funded/Doner_Registration.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "Email=\(textfieldemail.text!)&Password=\(textfieldpassword.text!)&MobileNo=\(textfieldmobile.text!)&UserType=\(butname)&LoginType=Normal"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        }

        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
        let msg = json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!

        self.activityIndi.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndi.hidesWhenStopped = true
        let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert box!", message: "\(msg!).",delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Are there no error messages, or web server responses you can include also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run your code with sample input

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://fundedindia.org/funded/Doner_Registration.php")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let email: String = "pardeep@yopmail.com"
    let password: String = "12345678"
    let mobileNo: String = "9599904029"
    let butname: String = "1"
    let postString = "Email=\(email)&Password=\(password)&MobileNo=\(mobileNo)&UserType=\(butname)&LoginType=Normal"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        }

        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary
        let msg = json.value(forKey: "message") as! NSString!

        let alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert box!", message: "\(msg!).",delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }
    task.resume()
```

Its responce status is not correct, please verify inputs and URl with your backend developer.

```
response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x604000425fe0> { URL: http://fundedindia.org/funded/Doner_Registration.php } { status code: 500, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 5759;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Thu, 07 Dec 2017 08:58:40 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
"X-Powered-By-Plesk" = PleskWin;
```

} })

"status code: 500" should be 200 for success.

Comment: so how should i put it sorry but i did not got the answer